# Make Keras fit_generator go through each sample exactly once

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

Let's say I have a dataset of 500 samples. I want the Keras fit_generator to go through each of the images exactly once. I have written this generator which I think should do exactly that, but I am amused by the way images are read. I am using keras 2.0.4 and Tensorflow 1.1.o

```
def generator_train(df,in_shape,num_features=13, batch_size=5):
    batch_images = np.zeros((batch_size, in_shape[0], in_shape[1], in_shape[2]))
    batch_indicators = np.zeros((batch_size,num_features))
    global i
    while 1:
        idx=b[i]
        print 'iter # {} : loading images : {} to {} ...'.format(i, idx,idx+batch_size)
        i=(i+1)%iters
        for j in range(batch_size):
            batch_images[j]=np.load(df.iloc[idx+j,-1])
            batch_indicators[j]=np.array(df.iloc[idx+j,:-1])
        yield batch_images, batch_indicators

batch_size=64
a=range(0,500,batch_size)
b=a # ideally it should be  - np.random.permutation(a)
adam = Adam(lr=1e-4, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(optimizer=adam,loss='mse')
iters=len(a)    
i=0
train_r_generator = generator_train(df_train,in_shape,num_features=13, batch_size=batch_size)
history = model.fit_generator(train_r_generator,steps_per_epoch=iters, nb_epoch=1, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
```

The output of this code is pasted below:

```
iter # 0 : loading images : 0 to 64 ...
Epoch 1/1
iter # 1 : loading images : 64 to 128 ...
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:509] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:158] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: UGC1AV3Y5RKC2
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:165] hostname: UGC1AV3Y5RKC2
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] libcuda reported version is: 375.39.0
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:363] driver version file contents: """NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  375.39  Tue Jan 31 20:47:00 PST 2017
GCC version:  gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 
"""
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:193] kernel reported version is: 375.39.0
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:300] kernel version seems to match DSO: 375.39.0
iter # 2 : loading images : 128 to 192 ...
iter # 3 : loading images : 192 to 256 ...
1/7 [===>..........................] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.5572iter # 4 : loading images : 256 to 320 ...
iter # 5 : loading images : 320 to 384 ...
2/7 [=======>......................] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.5454iter # 6 : loading images : 384 to 448 ...
iter # 0 : loading images : 0 to 64 ...
iter # 1 : loading images : 64 to 128 ...
3/7 [===========>..................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5680iter # 2 : loading images : 128 to 192 ...
iter # 3 : loading images : 192 to 256 ...
4/7 [================>.............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5560iter # 4 : loading images : 256 to 320 ...
iter # 5 : loading images : 320 to 384 ...
5/7 [====================>.........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5511iter # 6 : loading images : 384 to 448 ...
iter # 0 : loading images : 0 to 64 ...
6/7 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5552iter # 1 : loading images : 64 to 128 ...
iter # 2 : loading images : 128 to 192 ...
7/7 [==============================] - 15s - loss: 0.5520 - val_loss: 0.5472
Model saved.
```

I expected it to read images in the order like 0 to 64 for iter 0, 64 to 128 and so on, but the output is fishy. Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong?